# train the network with matlab matconvnet

Tags: matlab, regression, matconvnet, pdist

I want to train my network using matlab and matconvnet-1.0-beta25.
My problem is regression and I use `pdist` as loss function to get mse.
The inputs data is `56*56*64*6000` and the targets data is `56*56*64*6000` and network architecture is as follows:

```
opts.networkType = 'simplenn' ;
opts = vl_argparse(opts, varargin) ;

lr = [.01 2] ;

% Define network CIFAR10-quick
net.layers = {} ;

% Block 1
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.01*randn(5,5,64,32, 'single'), zeros(1, 32, 'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.05*randn(5,5,32,16, 'single'), zeros(1,16,'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', .1*lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.01*randn(5,5,16,8, 'single'), zeros(1, 8, 'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.05*randn(5,5,8,16, 'single'), zeros(1,16,'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', .1*lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.01*randn(5,5,16,32, 'single'), zeros(1, 32, 'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{0.05*randn(5,5,32,64, 'single'), zeros(1,64,'single')}}, ...
                           'learningRate', .1*lr, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 2) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
% Loss layer
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pdist') ;

% Meta parameters
net.meta.inputSize = [56 56 64] ;
net.meta.trainOpts.learningRate = [0.0005*ones(1,30) 0.0005*ones(1,10) 0.0005*ones(1,5)] ;
net.meta.trainOpts.weightDecay = 0.0001 ;
net.meta.trainOpts.batchSize = 100 ;
net.meta.trainOpts.numEpochs = numel(net.meta.trainOpts.learningRate) ;

% Fill in default values

net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net) ;
```

I change `getSimpleNNBatch(imdb, batch)` function in `ncnn_train` (the name of mine) as follows:

```
function [images, labels] = getSimpleNNBatch(imdb, batch)
    images = imdb.images.data(:,:,:,batch) ;
    labels = imdb.images.labels(:,:,:,batch) ;
    if rand > 0.5, images=fliplr(images) ; 
end
```

because my label is multi-dimensional.
Also I change `errorFunction` in `cnn_train` from `multiclasses` to `none`:

```
opts.errorFunction = 'none' ;
```

and change the `error` variable from:

```
% accumulate errors
error = sum([error, [...
  sum(double(gather(res(end).x))) ;
  reshape(params.errorFunction(params, labels, res),[],1) ; ]],2) ;
```

to:

```
% accumulate errors
error = sum([error, [...
  mean(mean(mean(double(gather(res(end).x))))) ;
  reshape(params.errorFunction(params, labels, res),[],1) ; ]],2) ;
```

**My first question is why the `res(end).x` third dimension in above command is one instead of 64? this is `56*56*1*100` (100 is the batch).**

**Have I made a mistake?**

here is the results:

```
train: epoch 01:   2/ 40: 10.1 (27.0) Hz objective: 21360.722
train: epoch 01:   3/ 40: 13.0 (30.0) Hz objective: 67328685.873
...
train: epoch 01:  39/ 40: 29.7 (29.6) Hz objective: 5179175.587
train: epoch 01:  40/ 40: 29.8 (30.6) Hz objective: 5049697.440
val: epoch 01:   1/ 10: 87.3 (87.3) Hz objective: 49.512
val: epoch 01:   2/ 10: 88.9 (90.5) Hz objective: 50.012
...
val: epoch 01:   9/ 10: 88.2 (88.2) Hz objective: 49.936
val: epoch 01:  10/ 10: 88.1 (87.3) Hz objective: 49.962
train: epoch 02:   1/ 40: 30.2 (30.2) Hz objective: 49.650
train: epoch 02:   2/ 40: 30.3 (30.4) Hz objective: 49.704
...
train: epoch 02:  39/ 40: 30.2 (31.6) Hz objective: 49.739
train: epoch 02:  40/ 40: 30.3 (31.0) Hz objective: 49.722
val: epoch 02:   1/ 10: 91.8 (91.8) Hz objective: 49.687
val: epoch 02:   2/ 10: 92.0 (92.2) Hz objective: 49.831
...
val: epoch 02:   9/ 10: 92.0 (88.5) Hz objective: 49.931
val: epoch 02:  10/ 10: 91.9 (91.1) Hz objective: 49.962
train: epoch 03:   1/ 40: 31.7 (31.7) Hz objective: 49.014
train: epoch 03:   2/ 40: 31.2 (30.8) Hz objective: 49.237
...
```

[here is my network schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRrer.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two inputs of `pdist` have got `nxmx64x100` size as below and as [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_nnpdist/) mentioned, the output of `pdist` has got the same height and width, but depth equal to one. About the correctness of error definition, you should debug and check the size and definition accurately. 
[image]

Comment: thanks, I add an image too, can i change this line in `pdist` from:
`y1 = sqrt(sum(d.*d,3)) ;`
to:
`y1 = sqrt(d.*d) ;`
?

Comment: So by this way you convert it to the 56x56x64x100 and the output dimension does not match with [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_nnpdist/). pay heed that if you want to reform the distance you should also consider backprop (not just forward passes)

Comment: but I can train and there is no error.
So what is your suggestion?

Comment: That makes no sense, you modify the forward passes and don't modify the back prob.

Comment: my last layer is `56*56*64` and my target is `56*56*64` and are equals.
So in backprop after loss layer computations, I have `56*56*64` too, so what is wrong in backprop? every thing seems ok (sorry, I'm confused)